# Generic tool to order by size in linux, understanding common unit suffixes

Tags: linux, disk-usage, sort, size

I can order a list of files / directories by size:

```
ls -lS
```

But if I am using `du` in human readable format:

```
du --max-depth=1 -h .
```

I get:

```
128K    ./something
3,3M    ./more
3,2M    ./even-more
...
```

Which is not ordered. Is there any standard tool to order this kind of data? Standard `sort` does not seem to support this. Do I need to roll my own?

Comment: GNU `sort` has `sort -h` (note that your `--max-depth=1` is GNU-specific already)

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Not sure how I missed that ... :(

Comment: These is no _standard_ tool that does this.

Comment: ... which isn’t a problem because `-h` isn’t a standard option for `du` either ;-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GNU `sort` has a `-h`/`--human-numeric-sort` option and `h` sort key flag to handle those (it expects 1024-based units (1023 sorts before  1K) which happens to be how GNU `du` counts  as well.

Now note that some precision is lost when you use `du -h`, so the order may end-up being wrong:

```
$ du -k a b
1212    a
1208    b
$ du -h a b | sort -h
1.2M    a
1.2M    b
```

As mentioned by @StephenKitt, you can work around it by telling `du` to give you the full precision and only convert to *human* format after sorting using for instance GNU `numfmt`:

```
$ du --block-size=1 a b | sort -n | numfmt --to=iec
1.2M b
1.2M a
```

(beware that spacing is affected). All of the above assume file names don't contain newline characters.

As for the generic question about ordering by size, `zsh`  globs have a `oL` glob qualifier for that (note that it's by size, not disk usage).

`ls -S` could be done (with GNU `ls` for its `-U` for unsorted):

```
ls -ldU -- *(oL)
```

For sorting by size after symlink resolution:

```
ls -LldU -- *(-oL)
wc -c -- *(-oL)
```

Answer (score 0):

The GNU variants of `ls` and `sort` understand `-h` (mnemonic: `-h`uman). You can either use `ls -lSh`, `ls -sSh` or `du -h … | sort -h`:

```
du --max-depth=1 -h . | sort -h
```

Keep in mind that `ls` won't report the size for directory contents.

Comment: `ls` does report the correct size for directories... But a directory’s size isn’t the size of the files it contains.

Comment: @StephenKitt That's what I meant, I'll try to rewrite it.